# Drive SDK change permission login required

Tags: php, permissions, google-drive-api, public, google-api-php-client

I try to upload file and share it to public. File is uploaded but I am unable to set the permissions. Here's my code:

```
<?php 
....
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_SECRET);
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setScopes(array( //just to be sure included all scopes
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly.metadata",
    "https://docs.google.com/feeds",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts"
));
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
...
//setting a token and successfully uploading a file 
...
$perm = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$perm->setType("anyone");
$perm->setRole("reader");
$perm->setValue(""); 
$perm->setWithLink(false);
try {
   $a = $service->permissions->insert($file->getId(), $perm);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

It doesn't throw any exceptions, returns an object.

By the way, these are permissions received from this file:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

**EDIT**
I've found in documentation that either value or id of permission must be sent. If I get this right, than id must be my application email? I tried `$perm->setId(GOOGLE_ID);` but nothing changed yet

Response dump:

```
Google_Http_Request Object
(
[batchHeaders:Google_Http_Request:private] => Array
        (
            [Content-Type] => application/http
            [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => binary
            [MIME-Version] => 1.0
        )

    [queryParams:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [requestMethod:protected] => POST
    [requestHeaders:protected] => Array
        (
            [content-type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
            [authorization] => Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        )

    [baseComponent:protected] => https://www.googleapis.com
    [path:protected] => /drive/v2/files/0B3_LVXxRuaPoT0xQYUZxbjlQTUE/permissions
    [postBody:protected] => {"id":"254599272636-1o7pt59olp5f1v4k4epui1k73oqonrl9@developer.gserviceaccount.com","role":"reader","type":"anyone"} //its a test value, i send my id instead of me
    [userAgent:protected] => 
    [canGzip:protected] => 
    [responseHttpCode:protected] => 
    [responseHeaders:protected] => 
    [responseBody:protected] => 
    [expectedClass:protected] => Google_Service_Drive_Permission
    [accessKey] => 
    )
```

**EDIT** 
I've also tried to use `$permissionId = $service->permissions->getIdForEmail($email);` method, but it didn't worked too, seems that nothing works that is associated with permissions.

Comment: Is the json code you displayed at the results in `$a`?

Comment: @Robbert no, it's displayed in a link that was retrieved with $a userPermission => selfLink, https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0BzWQyyYOE3TpV3VYT0thT2lsM1U/permissions/me but I dont know if it will work for you

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer here, [How to create a public Google Doc through the Drive API (PHP client)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291928/how-to-create-a-public-google-doc-through-the-drive-api-php-client), you should pass 'me' to setValue.

```
$permission = new Google_Permission();
$permission->setRole( 'writer' );
$permission->setType( 'anyone' );
$permission->setValue( 'me' );
$service->permissions->insert( $file->getId(), $permission );
```

The answer used `writer` as the permission level, but `reader` should work as well.

I see one other difference between your code and the referenced answer. The answer users `Google_DriveService` while you use `Google_Service_Drive`

```
$service = new Google_DriveService( $client );
```

Comment: Still testing, but the documentation is stating that reader level does not require value

Comment: No, it didnt helped, any ideas? @Robbert

Comment: With should i use as client id: app id or app email? Does it matter?

Comment: What's the value of `$a` use print_r($a). Maybe there's something there that will shed some light on the matter.

Comment: I noticed the same in more examples and more classes, i guess class names changes over SDK versions because of scaling. My version only includes Google_Service_Drive name.