# How to give a permission to restrict download a file from google drive?

Tags: php, google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am using Google drive to share my files like pdf or word. I want to give permission for shared person to view only that file, not download. From google drive interface I can set that permission, but programatically how to set this. I'm using PHP for my development.

Answer (score 0):

Use [permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)  to grant additional permissions to a user, group, or domain.

Although not entirely related, this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291928/how-to-create-a-public-google-doc-through-the-drive-api-php-client) demonstrates how to create permission for files using PHP:

```
//Give everyone permission to read and write the file
$permission = new Google_Permission();
$permission->setRole( 'writer' );
$permission->setType( 'anyone' );
$permission->setValue( 'me' );
$service->permissions->insert( $file->getId(), $permission );
```